# Angular - Get the selector name of the directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created a directive with multiple selectors, so I can access the same directive with different selectors. What I'm trying to achieve is **to get the selector name that called the directive** in my directive.

The following code will explain this even better:

So this is my multi-selector directive:

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

const inputs = [
  'someSelector.A', 'someSelector.B'
];

const selector = `
  [someSelector.A], [someSelector.B]
`;

@Directive({ selector, inputs })
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // I need to know here what is the current selector:
    // Is it: "someSelector.A" or "someSelector.B"?
  }
}
```

And this is how I would like to call the directive in the HTML:

```html
<element *someSelector.A></element>

<!-- Or: -->

<element *someSelector.B></element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can just check the inputs that match the selector in a few different ways

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective.A], [myDirective.B]',
})
export class MyDirective {
  @Input('myDirective.A')
  inputA;

  @Input('myDirective.B')
  inputB;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.inputA !== undefined) {
      // used directive A
    } else if (this.inputB !== undefined) {
      // used directive B
    }
  }
}
```

or your can check it in a setter:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective.A], [myDirective.B]',
})
export class MyDirective {
  @Input('myDirective.A')
  set inputA(valueA) {
    // will only run if A selector used
  }

  @Input('myDirective.B')
  set inputB(valueB) {
    // will only run if B selector used
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

in template:

```
<div *myDirective.A></div>
<div *myDirective.B></div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-92yazy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The problem with this is that I get an exception: `Error: NG0201: No provider for TemplateRef found.`, I think it's because I use `TemplateRef`

Comment: i didn't write structural directives. They should be easy to convert.

Comment: edited blitz / answer to be structural directives. to inject templateRef you need to use * selectors.

Comment: I checked the update to structural directive, the selectors are always undefined.

Comment: The stack blitz is right there bud. All works.

Comment: Only if I assign a value to it in the HTML like: `*myDirective.A="value"` then it is working... but this does not make sense.

Comment: look at the stackblitz. that is not what I'm doing. the value is `null` if you just use the selector with no value assignment. the value is `undefined` if you do not use the selector at all. either you're not differentiating between `null` and `undefined` properly, they're similar but not the same, or you're doing something else wrong that you didn't put in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so the way that flex is doing it, is that they are passing the inputs to the decorator, then the variables are generated on the directive. If the directive is not passed to the html element it is undefined on the directive inputs. It looks like this:

```js
export interface DirectiveAB {
  'someSelector.A': string;
  'someSelector.B': number;
}
type Selectors =  'someSelector.A' | 'someSelector.B';

const inputs = ['someSelector.A', 'someSelector.B'];

@Directive({ selector: '[someSelector.A], [someSelector.B]', inputs })
export class DirectiveAB implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.hasSelector('someSelector.A'));
    console.log(this.hasSelector('someSelector.B'));
  }

  hasSelector(selector: Selectors) {
    return typeof this[selector] !== 'undefined'
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- prints true for "A"; false for "B" -->
<div someSelector.A></div>

<!-- prints false for "A"; true for "B" -->
<div someSelector.B></div>
```

---

You could separate the directives into two and extend a root directive. This is really how directives should be used if you want to have different functionality for a different selector.

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '*' })
export class DirectiveRoot implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this);
    if (this instanceof DirectiveA) {
      console.log('Directive A!');
    }
  }
}

@Directive({ selector: '[someSelector.A]' })
export class DirectiveA extends DirectiveRoot {}

@Directive({ selector: '[someSelector.B]' })
export class DirectiveB extends DirectiveRoot {}
```

```html
<!-- prints DirectiveA to the console -->
<div someSelector.A></div>

<!-- prints DirectiveB to the console -->
<div someSelector.B></div>
```

---

Another option is to look at the element itself and check to see if the attribute exists:

```js
@Directive({ selector: '[someSelector.A], [someSelector.B]' })
export class DirectiveAB implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly ref: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.ref.element.nativeElement.hasAttribute('someSelector.A'));
    console.log(this.ref.element.nativeElement.hasAttribute('someSelector.B'));
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- prints true for "A"; false for "B" -->
<div someSelector.A></div>

<!-- prints false for "A"; true for "B" -->
<div someSelector.B></div>
```

Comment: What if I have 10+ selectors? This means I would need to declare 10+ directives in the app.module and it makes it very messy.

Comment: Could you possibly explain more as to why you need the name of the selector? If I know the reason maybe I can suggest a better option?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it as like an input parameter. And what I'm doing is to show or hide elements based on the screen size - exactly like angular flex-layout and how you use fxShow/fxHide.xs - I liked the way you work with those directives, and I want to implement my own logic with that.

Comment: I tried to go with the `.hasAttribute()` solution (I liked this approach) but unfortunately this throws an exception `this.ref.element.nativeElement.hasAttribute is not a function`

Comment: I have updated the answer with how flex-layout is doing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I get a compilation error on `this[selector]`: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DirectiveRoot'.

Comment: You need to create an interface and tell the compiler what the variables are

Comment: I checked the update - I still get the same compilation error

Comment: Did you add the type as well?